# Computer is dead, oh motherboard

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard

Last night my PC went fine, working perfectly. I shut down go to bed, and in the next morning surprise : https://youtu.be/LKUnUwn3I64

Nothing works, cannot power on, try to replace each piece (hard drive, ram, unplug the bios battery) nothing work. When the led is on, the CPU is rising in temperature but nothing more.

Do you have an idea what is it trying to tell me ? Thanks for any help

PS : it is an Asus G502VS

Comment: Can you hear the computer turn on, like do the fans make noise? If not I think the power supply is fried.

Comment: There's a quick test you can do on your power supply. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRhaI4W8d9s

Comment: Also, change the fuse in the wall plug (assuming you're in a country which has fused plugs)

Comment: @spikey_richie "The fact that the led can turn on and Orion can see the CPU getting warmer indicates that it is not a PSU or other power related issue. So the fuse and PSU do not need to be checked.

Comment: I didn't watch the video.

Comment: @spikey_richie its mentioned in the first post even...

Comment: I know, doesn't mean i watched it.

Answer (score 0):

I would perform a power reset in your case.

To do this, do the following depending on your situation:

**If you can remove the battery easily do option 1. If not, do option 2.**

---

**Option 1 - Power reset using battery removal**

Remove the battery from the system first, then unplug the powercord. Nothing should power the laptop. Once done, press and hold the powerbutton for 5 seconds, then once released tap it a few mores times. The laptop is not supposed to turn on or anything.

By doing this, you will drain the laptop from any residual electricity that may halt the system from turning on.

Now, put the battery back in and put the powercord back in too, and try to turn on the laptop. If the laptop does not turn on, keep the powercord plugged in for 30 minutes then try again.

---

**Option 2 - Power reset using power button**

In case the battery cannot be removed easily, the manufacturer will build in a hardware mechanism to do the same. In most of the cases this is accomplished by holding the powerbutton for a full minute (60 seconds).

- First unplug the power cable.
- Hold the powerbutton down for 60 seconds, then release it. Nothing will appear to happen.

Once released, attach the power cord and try turning it on. If it doesn't turn on straight away, keep the power cord plugged in for 30 minutes and try again after 30 minutes.

---

The reason you keep the power cord plugged in for 30 minutes and try later on both cases, is in case for some reason the battery is drained to such a low level that the system can't turn on. You charge it for 30 minutes which is usually enough to at least start the system.

If at this point the laptop does not turn on either, then either the battery is defective or worse. You can test this by trying to boot with the battery removed (in case of a removable battery) and only have the AC adapter plugged in.

Comment: I did try that before with no success. Thanks for the advice anyway. If I try with the battery removed, it do the same as in the video

Comment: So with the battery AND powercord removed, you pressed the power button a few times and then with only the power cord attatched it does not power on?

Comment: It does "power on" (the led turn on) when I plug the power cord, like in the video

Comment: My question is, did you perform the power reset as indicated? It is very important to have nothing attached to the laptop that can transmit any power to the laptop, then press the powerbutton a few times so it drains any residual power that may be in the transistors of the laptop. If that is completed and you attach power to the laptop, but the same thing happens, then a component on your laptop has died and the laptop needs to be replaced (repair is usually too expensive in this case).

Comment: Thanks LCPChip, indeed I try the power restet, but same result :( Anyway, thanks for the tips, might help other people